# Seeking an understanding of ServiceStack.Redis: IRedisClient.PublishMessage vs IMessageQueueClient.Publish

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis, redismqserver

I am having a hard time separating the `IRedisClient.PublishMessage` and `IMessageQueueClient.Publish` and realize I must be mixing something up.

ServiceStack gives us the option to listen for pub/sub broadcasts like this:

```
    static IRedisSubscription _subscription;
    static IRedisClient redisClientSub;
    static int received = 0;
    static void ReadFromQueue()
    {
        redisClientSub = redisClientManager.GetClient();
        _subscription = redisClientSub.CreateSubscription();

        _subscription.OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
        {
            try
            {
                received++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    
            }
        };

        Task.Run(() => _subscription.SubscribeToChannels("Test"));
    }
```

Looks nice, straightforward. But what about the producer?

When looking at the classes available, I thought that one could either user the `IRedisClient.PublishMessage(string toChannel, string message)` or `IMessageQueueClient.Publish(string queueName, IMessage message)`.

```
redisClient.PublishMessage("Test", json);
// or:     
myMessageQueueClient.Publish("Test", new Message<CoreEvent>(testReq));
```

In both cases, you specify the channel name yourself. This is the behaviour I am seeing:

- the subscriber above only receives the message if I use `IRedisClient.PublishMessage(string toChannel, string message)` and never if I use `IMessageQueueClient.Publish(string queueName, IMessage message)`
- If I publish using `IRedisClient.PublishMessage`, I expected the "Test" channel to be populated (if I view with a Redis browser), but it is not. I never see any trace of the queue (let's say I don't start the subscription, but producers adds messages)
- If I publish using `IMessageQueueClient.Publish(string queueName, IMessage message)`, the channel "Test" is created and the messages are persisted there, but never popped/fetched-and-deleted.

I want to understand the difference between the two. I have looked at source code and read all I can about it, but I haven't found any documentation regarding `IRedisClient.PublishMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mythz answered this on ServiceStack forum, [here](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/servicestack-redis-iredisclient-publishmessage-vs-imessagequeueclient-publish-explanation/8882/5).

He writes:

> These clients should not be used interchangeably, you should only be
> using ServiceStack MQ clients to send MQ Messages or the Message MQ
> Message wrapper.
>
> The redis subscription is low level API to create a Redis Pub/Sub
> subscription, a more useful higher level API is the Managed Pub/Sub
> Server which wraps the pub/sub subscription behind a managed thread.
>
> Either way, MQ Server is only designed to process messages from MQ
> clients, if you’re going to implement your own messaging
> implementation use your own messages & redis clients not the MQ
> clients or MQ Message class.

and

> No IRedisClient (& ServiceStack.Redis) APIs are for Redis Server, the
> PublishMessage API sends the redis PUBLISH command. IRedisSubscription
> creates a Redis Pub/Sub subscription, see Redis docs to learn how
> Redis Pub/Sub works. The ServiceStack.Redis library and all its APIs
> are just for Redis Server, it doesn’t contain any
> ServiceStack.Messaging MQ APIs.
>
> So just use ServiceStack.Redis for your custom Redis Pub/Sub
> subscription implementation, i.e. don’t use any ServiceStack.Messaging
> APIs which is for ServiceStack MQ only.