# ServiceStack Messaging API: Can it make a broadcast?

Tags: redis, servicestack, mq, servicestack.redis

As I have [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441969/seeking-an-understanding-of-servicestack-redis-iredisclient-publishmessage-vs-i) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409285/servicestack-mq-why-isnt-the-iredissubscription-onmessage-fired-when-manually), I am using [ServiceStack Messaging API](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) (`IMessageQueueClient.Publish`) as well as the more low-level `IRedisClient.PublishMessage`.

I use the Messaging API when I need a specific message/request to be processed by only one instance of a module/service, so even though I might have several modules running that all listens for `MyRequest`, only one service receives the message and processes it.

I use the `IRedisClient.PublishMessage` when I do a broadcast, a pub/sub situation, sending a request that everyone should receive that listens on that specific Redis channel.

However, I am in a situation where it would be useful to use the Messaging API, but do a broadcast, so that *all instances* that are listening to a specific message type, gets the message, not just the one.

(The reason for this is to streamline our usage of Redis and how we subscribe to events/request, but I will not get into details about this now. A little more background on this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520455/servicestack-json-serializer-how-can-i-change-the-default-serializer-globally).)

Is there a "broadcast way" for the Messaging API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the purpose of [ServiceStack Messaging](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) is simply to invoke ServiceStack Services via MQ. Any other MQ features is outside the purpose & scope of ServiceStack MQ, you'd need to instead develop against the MQ Provider APIs directly to access their broadcast features.

[Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) is a ServiceStack feature that supports broadcasting messages to subscribers of user-defined channels, but its a completely different implementation that serves a different use-case for sending "server push" real-time events over HTTP or gRPC, e.g. it doesn't use MQ brokers and pub/sub messages aren't persistent (i.e. only subscribers at time messages are sent will receive them).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will probably follow-up with a new SO question, a possible way to get what I am after using `HostContext.ResolveService<MyService>(new BasicRequest())`.